# C# Win. form - Outlook not accepting BCC parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, email, url, outlook

i am creating a URL link to directly **open Outlook's compose email page** where all the email will be populated as soon as the page appears but the problem is when i enter the below URL

> https://snt149.mail.live.com/?page=Compose&to=test1@gmail.com&cc=test2@gmail.com&BCC=test3@gmail.com

all the fields get filled up except the **BCC** one. Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong? Any piece of suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine with Outlook as Email application. In my case it's tested with 2010 Outlook version. You are hard coded to web email which does not make so much sense, does it??

```
<a href="mailto:abcd@gmail.com?subject=Works+Fine.&cc=efgh@gmail.com&bcc=ijkml@gmail.com&body=even+with+body+%2F.">abcd@gmail.com</a>
```

edit:
I cannot include a working test link here, probably due to HTML restrictions of SO

Comment: no i am talking about the browser based [outlook](http://outlook.com) and the emails are not hard coded it is just the final result of output my code generates.

Comment: then I would say the answer to your question is simply: " not possible" because their web interface does not support it due to the template that sort of hides the bcc.